# how to combine different data into one row?

Tags: r, row

I want to combine two records of datafram "df" with ID of "A" and "B" which lacks some data (NA)into one row with ID "C" (goal). I know matrix [ , ] can do this kind of work. But in the dataframe no row number is not available.

Below is my data.

```
df

ID    Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4    Y5   Y6

A     7     4     NA    NA    NA    NA

B     NA    NA     5    5     4     4
```

goal:

```
ID  Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4    Y5    Y6

C   7     4     5      5     4     4
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
 df1 %>%
   summarise(ID = 'C', across(where(is.numeric), na.omit))
 #  ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
 #1  C  7  4  5  5  4  4
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B"), Y1 = c(7L, NA), Y2 = c(4L, NA
), Y3 = c(NA, 5L), Y4 = c(NA, 5L), Y5 = c(NA, 4L), Y6 = c(NA, 
4L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! Assign values to the variables one bye one sounds time-consuming and unrealistic in the case of large amount of data.

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I mean it will be time consuming that you input Y1, Y2, .. by combining data one by one.

Comment: Sorry. I made a mistake. You are right. The second part in your answer is data. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, it works! Sorry for my confusion. I am the new guy in R.

Answer (score 3):

We could use `adorn_totals` from `janitor` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(janitor)
df1 %>%
  adorn_totals("row") %>% 
  slice(3)
```

Output:

```
    ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
 Total  7  4  5  5  4  4
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
as.data.frame(cbind(ID = 'C',t(apply(df[-1], 2, sum, na.rm = TRUE))))
  ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
1  C  7  4  5  5  4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Some base R options

- `colSums`

```
> cbind(ID = "C", data.frame(t(colSums(df[-1], na.rm = TRUE))))
  ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
1  C  7  4  5  5  4  4
```

- `na.omit` + `list2DF`

```
> list2DF(c(ID = "C", Map(na.omit, df[-1])))
  ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
1  C  7  4  5  5  4  4
```

Answer (score 1):

If in any case, you have pair of rows which you want to coalesce into each other, you may follow this simple strategy

```r
df <- structure(list(ID = c("A", "B", "C", "E"), Y1 = c(7L, NA, NA, 
                                                        7L), Y2 = c(4L, NA, 5L, NA), Y3 = c(NA, 5L, NA, 5L), Y4 = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                    5L, NA, 5L), Y5 = c(NA, 4L, 14L, NA), Y6 = c(NA, 4L, 5L, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  -4L), class = "data.frame")
df
#>   ID Y1 Y2 Y3 Y4 Y5 Y6
#> 1  A  7  4 NA NA NA NA
#> 2  B NA NA  5  5  4  4
#> 3  C NA  5 NA NA 14  5
#> 4  E  7 NA  5  5 NA NA
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(ID = (row_number()+1) %/% 2) %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), sum, na.rm =T))
#> # A tibble: 2 x 7
#>      ID    Y1    Y2    Y3    Y4    Y5    Y6
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     7     4     5     5     4     4
#> 2     2     7     5     5     5    14     5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>